# Inserting of data in cassandra

Tags: insert, nosql, cassandra

i have column family with the following structure

email,username,contact_number,subscribed_for

I've inserted a sample data like
ex:

KEY  email             username      contact_number  subscribed_for
01  test@gmail.com      test_usr      123456789       Entertainment

Now the scenario is the user can Subscribe for another category., If i insert data it updates the previous subscribed_for and keeps the updated one. How can i have the output like

KEY  email             username      contact_number  subscribed_for
01  test@gmail.com      test_usr      123456789       Entertainment
01  test@gmail.com      test_usr      123456789       Education

But, the key cannot be duplicate here. Can we take a key like auto increment and take the user_id column in the column family.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What client you are using for Cassandra? As Cassandra supports Dynamic column family, I am sure it is do-able. We are using Playorm and it is very much possible there with NoSqlOneToMany annotation.

Please see [this](https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/wiki/A-basic-%2aToMany-example-TestOneToMany)
for more details. As User and his Categories in your example above, an Account can have multiple Activities at the example given in the link.